# retrieve several url in a web page with condition for url with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a script which gives me the URLs of a website in Python with Selenium. I want to put an `<if>` to retrieve this web link containing a specific word "Word".

```
https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/recherche/synonyme/
https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/liste-theme/
https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/liste-usage/
https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/abatardir/ 
https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/abiose/ 
https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/abreviatif/ 
https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/paradoxal/
https://resultat-bac.linternaute.com/academie-aix-marseille
https://resultat-bac.linternaute.com/academie-lyon
```

My small condition

```
https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/abatardir/
https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/abiose/
https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/abreviatif/
https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/paradoxal/
```

A little help will be welcome.

Example:

```py
list_links=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

for i in list_links:
    url = i.get_attribute('href')
    print(url)
```

Comment: Is `if word in url:` what you are looking for? This is true if the url contains at least one occurence of word

Comment: This is really unclear. Do you mean you want to retrieve only the URLs which contain "definition"?

Answer (score 1):

Try using an if with in:

```
list_links=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

word = "word"
for i in list_links:
    url = i.get_attribute('href')
    if word in url:
        print(url)
```

Comment: @user13947346 glad I could help :)

Comment: @user13947346 It would mean a lot to me if you could pick my answer as correct. Thank you! :)